# "truth value of an array" Error : Where is this array?

Tags: python, arrays, conditional-statements

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous.  Use a.any() or a.all()

I know this error means one of my truth value isn't a truth value, but how is it possible ?

Here is the line with the error :

```
if (((indicator in calcs_param and timeRange in calcs_param[indicator]) or (indicator in queries_param and timeRange in queries_param[indicator]))) and ((field is None) or (field[0:2] in ["=/", "=-"]) or (field[-1:] in ["/", "-"])):
```

`field` is supposed to be a string, `indicator` and `timeRange` also, and `cals_param` and `queries_param` some dictionaries.

To debug it, I tried to do this before :

```
    if (isinstance(indicator, (list, tuple))):
        logger.warn("indicator \"" + indicator[0] + "\" is an array")
    if (isinstance(timeRange, (list, tuple))):
        logger.warn("timeRange \"" + timeRange[0] + "\" is an array")
```

But nothing has been logged.

Furthermore, what I don't understand is that I only use AND and OR with "x in y" and "x is None", nothing of this should be an array, right?!

Comment: Can you share more details...a bigger code snippet or something else?

Comment: Could you try building the conditional expression step by step, to see more specifically where the error occurs?

Comment: You state `indicator` and `timeRange` are strings, yet you compare them to a list or tuple with `isinstance()`? Just wrap the logging statement in a try except clause (`TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable` will result if indicator or timeRange can't be indexed).

Comment: @Evert Thanks, I'm now sure they are String !

So how could this happen ?